# Não pode ser atribuído, pois é somente leitura após de fazer um "Join"

Tags: c#, html5, entity-framework-6

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listar_Json()
{
  var id = 5;
  var search = Request["search[value]"]; //Aqui pega valor digitado no input, digamos que ele digitou 100.000,01

  var query = database.Posts.Join(database.Post_Metas, 
           post => post.ID, 
           meta => meta.Post_ID, 
           (post, meta) => new 
           { 
              valor1 = post.Money1, //100000,01
              valor2 = meta.Money2  //100000,02
           })
        .Where(x => x.Post.ID == id)
        .ToList();

foreach (var item in query )
{
   item.valor1 = item.valor1 ????  //100.000,01
}

query = query
    .Where(x => (x.Money1.ToString() ?? "").Contains(search)
    .ToList();

   return Json(new { data = query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
<table id="data_grid" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Valor1</th>
            <th>Valor2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Quero retornar valor **100000,01** para **100.000,01**. Para isso, preciso usar um `foreach` para modificar. Não consigo modificar `valor1`, porque fala que não pode ser atribuído, é somente leitura.

Como posso eu posso modificar valor?

Comment: Não basta fazer um `valor1 = string.Format("{0:N}",post)`, não?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, já tentei essa tbm, recebo erro: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Então, acredito que fazer um select depois do where seja o melhor.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, recebo mesmo erro, tem como eu tirar essa coisa de "somente leitura" ?

Comment: É somente leitura e você realmente não consegue atribuir, o que pretende? Exibir em uma View???

Comment: Isso mesmo Virgílio, Pretendo exibir na  view.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda poste sua `View` seu `Controller` e o método responsável para que eu possa te propor algo! não precisa formatar assim pelo visto.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei post. No banco de dados está gravado como `100000,01` digamos que usuário digitou `100.000,01`. Como posso obter a linha que contem`100000,01` ?

Comment: você está filtrando pelo valor moeda? o usuário na tela digitou no padrão Brasileiro e no Banco está no formato diferente? é isso??? se precisa filtrar na base pelo dados enviados da tela?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic isso mesmo !!!

Comment: @MatheusMiranda acredito que vc tenha que guardar o valor no banco de dados sendo numeric mesmo (casa decimal com . no sql server, por exemplo). Se o usuario digitar 100.000,01, você teria que remover os pontos e depois converter para decimal novamente formatando o numero. Mas isso tem que ser antes de passar o valor para o linq, pois se usar format ele vai dar pau mesmo pois ele vai tentar converter o método em um sql valido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só converte o valor que vem do usuário para o valor igual do banco com `Convert.ToDecimal` por exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listar_Json()
{
    var id = 5; 
    var search = Request["search[value]"];     
    decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(search.Replace(".",""));

    var query = database.Posts.Join(database.Post_Metas, 
           post => post.ID, 
           meta => meta.Post_ID, 
           (post, meta) => new 
           { 
              post, meta
           })
        .Where(x => x.post.ID == id && x => x.post.Money1 == value)
        .ToList();


   return Json(new { data = query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

apesar que parece que tem problemas por tem dois filtros que eu acabei unindo por causa da sua resposta e o `join` talvez sem necessidade.

Quando já está materializado a expressão do `Linq` (***exemplo:*** `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, *etc*), pode então trabalhar a informação na parte de objetos, ou seja, `Linq to Object`, mas, tome cuidado para que o seu desempenho não seja comprometido, para volumes pequenos não tem tantos problemas de desempenho, só mesmo para grande volumes, ou seja, vai depender da quantidade de linhas retornadas, mas, é uma forma de já enviar a informação com suas próprias características.

***Exemplo:***

```
var query = database.Posts.Join(database.Post_Metas, 
           post => post.ID, 
           meta => meta.Post_ID, 
           (post, meta) => new 
           { 
              post, meta
           })
        .Where(x => x.post.ID == id && x => x.post.Money1 == value)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => x.Money1.ToString('N2'));
```

Comment: @MatheusMiranda não entendi bem, mas, se está falando de formatação?

Comment: Se pode fazer um select depois do `ToList().Select()`, por exemplo!, porque ai você pode, porque ai é objeto já! o que se não pode fazer quando é na SQL ai que não pode e fica `ReadOnly`!

Comment: Não indicaria esse outra forma ai !!! @MatheusMiranda

Comment: @MatheusMiranda pronto eu editei colocando um texto simples vamos apagar esses comentários?